# MS Edge test automation - non selenium

Tags: java, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

I am currently working on an implementation of **Microsoft Edge** to my company's automated tests, but the problem is that we have our own system and not using selenium, so I have a hard time finding how to go about coding handles in for Edge (also in Java).

Can this be done without selenium?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would do so using the WebDriver API.

See [WebDriver (Selenium 2) API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644868/webdriver-selenium-2-api-documentation)

and https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html

ref:https://m.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/4knatt/java_automation_of_microsoft_edge_without_selenium/